# Mass redshift degeneracy for binary black holes at all order in post-Newtonian perturbation theory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, redshift, post-newtonian

When you compute the inspiral signals of a binary black hole to lowest order in the post-Newtonian formalism, and study how this solution propagates through an expanding spacetime, you find that the redshift $z$ cannot be extracted from the signal. It turns out that the mass scales you measure $m_d$ are related to the astrophysical mass scales $m_s$ as $m_d = (1+z)m_s$, and only $m_d$ is accessible from inspiral signals.

Is this statement true to all orders in the post-Newtonian formalism? If so, is there a fundamental reason for this?

Comment: Can you please cite a source (possibly a textbook or accessible article)  where these calculations are carried out?

Comment: For the calculation see, for instance, Michele Maggiore's book: Gravitational Waves: Volume 1: Theory and Experiments, sec. 4.1.4 Binaries at cosmological distances

Answer (score 1):

This is true in general for binary black holes, not just in any post-Newtonian approximation*. The fundamental reason for this is scale invariance of general relativity. Up to an overall scaling the waveform of the merger of two black holes with total mass $10^6$ solar masses looks exactly the same as the waveform from a binary with a total mass of 10 solar masses (with the same mass-ratio, dimensionless spins, eccentricity, etc.). Redshift applies exactly this same type of scaling.

To break this degeneracy you'd need some physical effect that introduce a new independent (known) length scale to the problem, e.g. the equation of state of a neutron star.

*) Note that at "all orders in the post-Newtonian formalism" is a weaker statement since the post-Newtonian series is not expected to converge for any finite value of the PN expansion parameter. It is theoretically possible for something to be true at all orders in PN theory and not be true in general.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification concerning the post-Newtonian approximation. However, it would be useful to see this from a specific formula, and not simply from the statement that 'GR is scale invariant'.

Comment: @konstle It follows from the fact that the vacuum Einstein equation does not contain any dimensionfull constants, it does not have any sense of scale.

Comment: Another way to see it is that the Einstein tensor is invariant under constant rescalings of the metric (which you can see easily by noting that each term in its definition contains an equal number of factors of the metric and its inverse (or their derivatives).

Comment: If GR does not have any scale, then it should also be impossible to extract the chirp mass, shouldn't it?

Comment: @konstle The chirp mass has the same scale ambiguity with respect to the redshift. Of course, your gravitational wave detector itself has a scale, consequently, we can measure the chirp mass (and the individual masses) in the detector frame.